# How to use maps in the Boneh Gentry Waters encryption scheme?

Tags: pairings, broadcast-encryption

I am reading the source of `pbc_bce` library which implements the [Boneh Gentry Waters broadcast encryption scheme](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/abstracts/broadcast.html). In this paper the authors use for their construction a bilinear group $G$ and a bi-linear map $e$ but in the source of `pbc_bce` I find the implementation of the bi-linear map. Which map is used for the pairing?

**EDIT**

I ve read the paper a lot of times, but I am not sure that I have understood it. Their first construction begins with "Let $G$ be a bi-linear group..". The proof that $D(E(K)) = K$ make use of the properties of a bi-linear map, e.g.: $e(a \cdot x,b) = e(a,b) \cdot e(x,b)$. That's why expected them to expand on the maps. Yet, they didn't.

The paper merely states on page 1 and 2: *`Our constructions use groups with an efficiently computable bilinear map.`* while section “2.2  Bilinear Maps” limits itself to (quote) *`briefly review the necessary facts about bilinear maps and bilinear map groups.`*

Am I missing something? How is this not related to some **specific** maps?